# chrome.storage.local.get empty after chrome.runtime.reload() - packaged app

Tags: local-storage, google-chrome-app

I'm using chrome storage in my app which was working fine. The process is very simple. User enters email and password, app verifies them using XHR request and maintain the session by using `chrome.storage.local.set`. Once the session is set i reload the app using `chrome.runtime.reload()`. On every reload i use checkLogin function to verify if the session is active or not. It was working fine. But now i'm getting this error:

[image]

It seems that the storage gets empty after reloading the app and the app cannot find the keyword in the storage and returning undefined error.

Here the code that is called once the user is authenticated:

```
postLogin = function (resultData) {
if (resultData.authStatus == 1) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'userData': resultData}, function(){
        console.log("session saved");
    });
    chrome.runtime.reload()
}
else {
    $("#result").html(resultData.authMsg);
    $("#result").attr('style', 'display: inline-block !important');
}
return false
}
```

Once the app is reloaded i check the saved session:

```
checkLogin = function () {
console.log(chrome.storage);
chrome.storage.local.get("userData",function(result) {
    userData = result.userData;
    if (userData && userData.authStatus == 1) {
        console.log("--- user signed In ---")
        return true;
    }
    console.log(" ---- unable to find user session ----")
    $("#auth-dialog").attr('style', 'display: inline !important');
    return false;
})
}
```

At this point i'm getting the error i attached in the screenshot above. I also used `console.log(chrome.storage);` to verify storage status and it returned undefined.
The weird thing is once i relaunch the app manually the `.get` part of the code works fine. At first, it shows error i had to reload the page in order to get the stored storage value.

Manifest:

```
{
  ...
  "permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "nativeMessaging" , "storage" ],
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The issue is not with the `chrome.storage` as mentioned in the post heading. The main issue with `chrome.runtime.reload()`. After initial app launch, whenever i call `chrome.runtime.reload()` as soon as the app reloads anything starting from `chrome.` doesn't work.

Comment: Is this an app, or an extension? It should be only one. Please [edit] your question to include only the appropriate tag.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: It's a chrome packaged app. I've removed extension tag. updated the question with related part of manifest. The image is only for the error screenshot, rest is the app code pasted using code tags.

Comment: I've updated the question and added some more code which will hopefully clarify the process.

Comment: FYI: This is not [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). It's often called Chrome storage, extension storage, etc. However, it's quite separate from `localStorage`.

Comment: I understand that the image is of an error. While it's OK to have the image *in addition to* the error in text format, having it in text format is important, as it's one of the things people search for when trying to find solutions to their problems.

Comment: Why do you reload the app? Tip: don't do it at all, or do it in the callback of the previous storage function.

Comment: I know reload can be avoided. I learned chrome app development on this app so there are some flaws. I developed this app last year and it's been working fine till now. I still can't understand what caused this issue. As you suggested i triggered the reload from .set function but still same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a solution but i've found a workaround for it. My original assumption was that after reloading the app `chrome.storage` doesn't work because that's the first thing my app check. After some more debugging i found out that whenever i call `chrome.runtime.reload()` as soon as the app reloads anything starting from `chrome.` doesn't work. The issue is with the reloading the app To test this i've removed everything from the app just a log message showing manifest details `console.log(chrome.runtime.getManifest())` and one button "Reload" on click event it calls `chrome.runtime.reload()`. At initial app launch, everything works fine with a console log message showing manifest details. When i click Reload button and the app reloads it shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.getManifest() is not a function

I tried using other functions like `chrome.storage.local.set/get` with the same undefined error.

To resolve this, the workaround is to create a new window instead of reloading the app and close the previous one.

```
chrome.app.window.create(
    'main.html',
    opt);
setTimeout(function () {
    //close previous window
}, 300);
```

If anyone having the same issue and found a better/cleaner workaround for this, please share.

Comment: I have similar problem, occasionally, my Chrome App run too "fast" when starting up and chrome.runtime.getManifest or chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo is undefined at the moment, I think I have to use your solution likewise. I traced the chrome code, found that:

Comment: "apiFunctions.setHandleRequest('getManifest', function() {
    return runtimeNatives.GetManifest();
  });"
chrome bug caused by an async code? though, I have no idea.